Is the Light God’s Wisdom?
In Proverbs 8, God’s Wisdom is personified as the first of God’s works - present with him from the beginning of creation. The narrative describes Wisdom as present even during the creation of the heavens (the second day of creation). However, it does not say that Wisdom was present when God created the light on the first day. And since the light was the first creation, this would seem to imply that the Light is God’s Wisdom.
Is this association made in Judaism. Or, if the Wisdom is not the Light, how is Wisdom interpreted as part of the creation story? And what is the Light?

According to the sages, the light of the first day of creation is indeed referring to the light of wisdom concealed within the torah, which, as the Talmud says (Sotah 12a) is the same light that filled the house when Moses was born, as it says that Moses's mother saw that "he was good" (Exodus 2:2), which is the same language used for the light.

@User123 very cool  Thanks!

This site is very strict about its no comparative religion questions rule, so this is going to very likely get voted closed. While I understand that the part about Christianity is useful context, all it will ultimately serve is to get the question closed so I recommend removing it as there is enough context without it.

@RabbiKaii I edited it as you wrote.

The Light of the first day refers to Hashem's intent and goal in Creation, and is therefore God's Will. Will always precedes, and acts as the power of, Wisdom.
God's purpose is that the world be transformed to Light, i.e. His very Self should find a dwelling in the lowest world.
The Light of the first day was hidden away, and a ray of it was channeled into the creation of every detail of all that was created. In this mode, this small vector of a ray is more associated with Kindness. The act(s) of Creation is indeed a pure act of Kindness, as what is Kindness if not giving. In this mode, the light is hidden, and it is the mission of the Jewish people to expose it through Torah and Mitzvot.
The Torah is where God hid the Light, and its Wisdom is indeed associated with the Light as God's desire is expressed as a plan; a blueprint, and hence the association with Light and Wisdom (Sotah 12a). The Light is also associated with Goodness, which is what every phrase "it was good" is really referring to - the Light that is in all the details of creation, that will one day be revealed.
A practical lesson, that also helps us understand this deep idea, is how we also go about fulfilling our desires. At first, we transform the desire into a plan, and then we hide away the desire somewhere in the background, while we execute the plan. The desire is what empowers the entire process, but during that process it is not focussed on, but when the plan is accomplished, the desire is able to be fully revealed once again, in enjoying the fruits of the labour.
See this Sicha for more information, explanation, and plenty of sources.
